# How does Backbone.js implement events?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

**Clarification:**

I'm only targeting modern browsers that support createEvent, addEventListener, etc....

**Question**

I mean natively, in JavaScript.  A search shows that they are not using `createEvent()`.

I'm looking here in the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) for answers but did not find any.

I did a search for `createEvent()` in the [source here](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js) but there were no hits.

How does backbone implement events from a native language perspective?

Are they using the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)?

If JavaScript already has custom events ( via `createEvent()` ) available, and  event listeners available as well ( `addEventListener()` why don't they use the built in events?

Comment: dood, just search for "events" in the source code you linked to. it's well documented in there. close this question asap.

Comment: because builtin events are not cross browser first then second backbone event class does some stuff builtin events do not ( namespaces ,etc ...).

Comment: well some folks using backbone are not.

Comment: Regarding the question you just deleted, you are misunderstanding hoisting. Only the variable declaration gets hoisted, not the assignment. So doing `*your IIFE*; var SCommon = {...};` is actually equivalent to `var SCommon; *your IIFE*; SCommon = {...};`. Note how the value of `SCommon` is `undefined` despite the hoisting. Just thought I'd let you know.

Comment: @pure_code I am not "off on tangent", I'm just trying to explain why your code fails. When you evaluate `this.S.Common.cacheElements(this.E);`, the value of `this.S.Common` is undefined. The reason this is so is because `this.S.Common == SCommon`, whereas `SCommon` is undefined. I explained why `SCommon` is undefined in my previous comment.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. Why do we have to close down all the interesting questions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Why isn't Backbone using native events?

It doesn't make sense to use native events for anything but a backbone view.  Backbone provides event management for [models](http://backbonejs.org/#Model), [collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection), [and generally](http://backbonejs.org/#Events)

Native events (via `createEvent`, `addEventListener`) are tied to a DOM node.  Models and collections are not associated to a DOM node - you'd have to jump through a lot of unnecessary hoops to reuse that code.

#### Do Backbone events follow the observer pattern?

Not really, no.  `Backbone.Events` is a lot closer to the [publish-subscribe pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).  An object maintains a list of event listeners for a named event (via `on`), and then that object triggers a call to those listeners via `trigger` when it wants to fire an event.

#### How are Backbone events implemented?

At its core, Backbone maintains an array of event listeners per event (and in older versions of backbone, it used to use a linked list; that was slower).  Each object maintains its own list of listeners; there is no central registry.

On `trigger`, backbone calls all the listeners registered for that event; and it also calls any listeners for the special-cased `all` event.

Comment: But what's the benefit?  DOM nodes are _not_ free; you'd be introducing a considerable bit of memory overhead, and most likely you'd be taking a performance hit.

Comment: Again, what's the benefit of jumping through all those hoops?  DOM-based events manage a bunch of unnecessary behaviors that Backbone has zero use for (bubbling, cancellation).  Creating event objects is awkward.  Etc.  Plus, Backbone's event implementation [appears to be just as fast](http://jsperf.com/dom-events-vs-backbone) as native events.

Comment: Yeah, take a look at the js perf link in my previous comment.  Note that both implementations are just as fast as each other.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone does it [like this](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/0.9.10/backbone.js#L64-L227). It's 163 lines of code counting blanks and comments.

To clarify the **how**

- Basic things like regex to split event names, a simple registry of bound listeners that are simple object literals
- An api of `on|bind`, `off|unbind`, `trigger`, `once`, `listenTo`, `stopListening`

As for **why**, it's based on design decisions that the author and contributors have made that they feel fit the goals and style of the project. The namespacing and multi-event bindings are nice conveniences given common patterns used by backbone models, collections, and views.

**Yes**, they are using the observer pattern. All event-based systems incorporate an implementation of the observer pattern. Events, pub/sub, and observer are, speaking broadly, synonymous, although some may find it important to distinguish them when talking in detail.

Comment: jQuery's version - http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Yes, if by "funny" you mean "intentionally used the same function name". Backbone's use of `$.ajax` also has some jquery tie-ins.

Comment: They're following the pattern set up by both jQuery and [Node](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html), yeah.  It's better to have a consistent interface - less surprising to anyone picking up Backbone!